# Unexpected poor/slow performance of GeoPandas clip operation

Tags: python, geopandas, clip

I have a vector based grid stored in a GeoPandas dataframe. Each grid cell is a polygon that is 100x100 meters in size, and there is about ~2 million grid cells.

I am performing a simple [clip](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.clip.html) operation using a single polygon boundary mask.

I've had no issues running this clip function many times before, and it would run on the order of a few seconds. For some reason, after some modifications to my Conda environment recently, the clip operation has slowed down *significantly*. It now takes more than 10 minutes to perform the clipping, which took only a few seconds before.

**Does anyone know the underlying root cause of this apparent performance issue?*

I've tried reverting back to previous "revision" of my Conda environment, but that doesn't seem to resolve the performance issue. I've also tried to install GeoPandas in a fresh Conda environment, and this didn't fix the issue either.

I'm really perplexed because I'm certain that this clip operation in my code was never a bottleneck before. If it took ~10 minutes every time I ran that segment of code, I would have definitely noticed it before. This has only happened recently, within the last few weeks.

Code sample below.

```
import os
import geopandas as gpd
import pyproj
import shapely.geometry 

# read boundary file
la_boundary = gpd.read_file('/path/to/file/la_county_boundary.geojson')

# create grid that covers the extent of LA County, set at 'X' m resolution
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = la_boundary.total_bounds

# create a little buffer for extent
xmin = xmin - 0.005
ymin = ymin - 0.005
xmax = xmax + 0.005
ymax = ymax + 0.005

# Set up transformers, EPSG:3857 is metric, same as EPSG:900913
to_proxy_transformer = pyproj.Transformer.from_crs('epsg:4326', 'epsg:3857', always_xy=True)

# Create corners of rectangle to be transformed to a grid
sw = shapely.geometry.Point((xmin, ymin))
ne = shapely.geometry.Point((xmax, ymax))

# Project corners to target projection
transformed_sw = to_proxy_transformer.transform(sw.x, sw.y) # Transform NW point to 3857
transformed_ne = to_proxy_transformer.transform(ne.x, ne.y) # .. same for SE

def create_grid(sw, ne, stepsize):
    grid_cells = []
    x = sw[0]
    while x < ne[0]:
        y = sw[1]
        while y < ne[1]:
            x1 = x + stepsize
            y1 = y + stepsize
            cell = shapely.geometry.box(x, y, x1, y1)
            grid_cells.append(cell)
            y += stepsize
        x += stepsize
    ah_grid = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid_cells, columns=['geometry'], crs='epsg:3857')
    ah_grid = ah_grid.to_crs('epsg:4326')
    return ah_grid

ah_grid = create_grid(transformed_sw, transformed_ne, 100) # 100 meter resolution

# clip grid using boundary as a mask
clipped_grid = gpd.clip(ah_grid, la_boundary)
```

Boundary file attributes:

```
print(la_boundary.is_valid, la_boundary.crs, la_boundary.geom_type, la_boundary.total_bounds)

0 True dtype: bool 
epsg:4326 
0 MultiPolygon dtype: object 
[-118.94463063 33.7036694 -117.64637388 34.82330643]
```

List of packages in Conda environment:

```
# packages in environment at /home1/kojoseph/.conda/envs/geo_test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
arrow-cpp                 9.0.0           py310h9c91e85_7_cpu    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.0.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
attrs                     22.1.0             pyh71513ae_1    conda-forge
aws-c-cal                 0.5.11               h95a6274_0    conda-forge
aws-c-common              0.6.2                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
aws-c-event-stream        0.2.7               h3541f99_13    conda-forge
aws-c-io                  0.10.5               hfb6a706_0    conda-forge
aws-checksums             0.1.11               ha31a3da_7    conda-forge
aws-sdk-cpp               1.8.186              hb4091e7_3    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
blosc                     1.21.1               h83bc5f7_3    conda-forge
boost-cpp                 1.78.0               h75c5d50_1    conda-forge
branca                    0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                h166bdaf_8    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h166bdaf_8    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py310h5764c6d_1005    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.9.24            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            ha61ee94_1014    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.9.24          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1          py310h255011f_2    conda-forge
cfitsio                   4.1.0                hd9d235c_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
click                     8.1.3           py310hff52083_1    conda-forge
click-plugins             1.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
cligj                     0.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
contourpy                 1.0.5           py310hbf28c38_0    conda-forge
cryptography              38.0.2          py310h597c629_1    conda-forge
curl                      7.86.0               h7bff187_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.6.3           py310hd8f1fbe_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.5.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
fiona                     1.8.22          py310h60a68a4_0    conda-forge
folium                    0.13.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.1               hc2a2eb6_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.38.0          py310h5764c6d_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               hca18f0e_0    conda-forge
freexl                    1.0.6                h166bdaf_1    conda-forge
gdal                      3.5.2           py310hb7951cf_5    conda-forge
geopandas                 0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
geopandas-base            0.12.0             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
geos                      3.11.0               h27087fc_0    conda-forge
geotiff                   1.7.1                ha76d385_4    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.1               h27087fc_0    conda-forge
gflags                    2.2.2             he1b5a44_1004    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h36c2ea0_2    conda-forge
glog                      0.6.0                h6f12383_0    conda-forge
grpc-cpp                  1.47.1               h05bd8bd_6    conda-forge
hdf4                      4.2.15               h9772cbc_4    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.12.2          nompi_h2386368_100    conda-forge
icu                       70.1                 h27087fc_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.16.2             pyh210e3f2_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.5.0              pyh41d4057_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.1             pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
joblib                    1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
json-c                    0.16                 hc379101_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.4.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.11.1          py310hff52083_0    conda-forge
kealib                    1.4.15               ha7026e8_1    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.4.4           py310hbf28c38_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.3               h3790be6_0    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 hddcbb42_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.39                 hc81fddc_0    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libabseil                 20220623.0      cxx17_h48a1fff_4    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h166bdaf_8    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h166bdaf_8    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h166bdaf_8    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.2                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.86.0               h7bff187_0    conda-forge
libdap4                   3.20.6               hd7c4107_2    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.14                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               h9b69904_4    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libgdal                   3.5.2                hf663712_5    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            12.2.0              h69a702a_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.2.0              h337968e_19    conda-forge
libglib                   2.74.1               h7a41b64_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.2.0              h65d4601_19    conda-forge
libgoogle-cloud           2.2.0                h838d150_1    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libkml                    1.3.0             h37653c0_1015    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0           16_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libnetcdf                 4.8.1           nompi_h21705cb_104    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.47.0               hdcd2b5c_1    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.21          pthreads_h78a6416_3    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.38               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libpq                     14.5                 hd77ab85_1    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.21.8               h6239696_0    conda-forge
librttopo                 1.1.0               hf730bdb_11    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h36c2ea0_1    conda-forge
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_4    conda-forge
libspatialite             5.0.1               hfbd986c_21    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.39.4               h753d276_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               haa6b8db_3    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.2.0              h46fd767_19    conda-forge
libthrift                 0.16.0               h491838f_2    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                h55922b4_4    conda-forge
libutf8proc               2.7.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.10.3               h7463322_0    conda-forge
libzip                    1.9.2                hc869a4a_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
mapclassify               2.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.1           py310h5764c6d_2    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.6.1           py310h8d5ebf3_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
munch                     2.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h27087fc_1    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
networkx                  2.8.7              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nspr                      4.32                 h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
nss                       3.78                 h2350873_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.23.4          py310h53a5b5f_1    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.0                h7d73246_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1q               h166bdaf_1    conda-forge
orc                       1.8.0                h09e0d61_0    conda-forge
packaging                 21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.5.1           py310h769672d_0    conda-forge
parquet-cpp               1.5.1                         2    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.37                hc3806b6_1    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    9.2.0           py310hbd86126_2    conda-forge
pip                       22.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
poppler                   22.10.0              h92391eb_0    conda-forge
poppler-data              0.4.11               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
postgresql                14.5                 hdeef612_1    conda-forge
proj                      9.1.0                h93bde94_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.31             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.3           py310h5764c6d_1    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyarrow                   9.0.0           py310h225c066_7_cpu    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pygeos                    0.13            py310h5e49deb_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.13.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 22.1.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyproj                    3.4.0           py310hb1338dc_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.10.6          h582c2e5_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.10                    2_cp310    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.5             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     24.0.1          py310h330234f_0    conda-forge
re2                       2022.06.01           h27087fc_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1.2                h0f457ee_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
rtree                     1.0.1           py310hbdcdc62_0    conda-forge
s2n                       1.0.10               h9b69904_0    conda-forge
scikit-learn              1.1.2           py310h0c3af53_0    conda-forge
scipy                     1.9.3           py310hdfbd76f_0    conda-forge
setuptools                65.5.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
shapely                   1.8.5           py310h5e49deb_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.9                hbd366e4_1    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.39.4               h4ff8645_0    conda-forge
stack_data                0.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
threadpoolctl             3.1.0              pyh8a188c0_0    conda-forge
tiledb                    2.11.3               h1e4a385_1    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h27826a3_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.2             py310h5764c6d_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzcode                    2022e                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2022e                h191b570_0    conda-forge
unicodedata2              14.0.0          py310h5764c6d_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.11            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xerces-c                  3.2.4                h55805fa_1    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.7.2                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xyzservices               2022.9.0           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h166bdaf_4    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.2                h6239696_4    conda-forge
```

Comment: The problem seems to be with la_boundary. Please: `print(la_boundary.is_valid, la_boundary.crs, la_boundary.geom_type, la_boundary.total_bounds)`.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca Here is the output when I print what you requested. 
0    True
dtype: bool epsg:4326 0    MultiPolygon
dtype: object [-118.94463063   33.7036694  -117.64637388   34.82330643]

Comment: Hi @JosephKo, please include it in the post. It's strange, I tested your script and runs ok here. Maybe need to include also the exact version of libraries and conda channel used.

Comment: @GabrielDeLuca I've added the output of the print statement as well as the packages in my conda environment to the post. Quick question: when you say it ran "ok" approximately how fast did it run?

Comment: The clip algorithm was adjusted recently (see https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/2366), and those changes were merged into version 0.11.0. Try forcing geopandas to be 0.10.2 or earlier to see if performance goes back to what it was.